# Structure property - Expression Is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment

Tags: .net, vb.net, class, data-structures

I have two classes:

```
Public Class SubiektGT
    Dim daneKlienta As SklepPobieranieDanych = New SklepPobieranieDanych(Me)

    Public Sub PrzefiltrujDaneKontrahenta()
    If daneKlienta.DaneKontrahenta.adres_fv = "" Then
        daneKlienta.DaneKontrahenta.adres_fv = daneKlienta.DaneKontrahenta.adres_wys 'ERROR
    End If
End Sub
End Class



Public Class SklepPobieranieDanych
    Public Structure Kontrahent
        Public adres_wys As String
        Public adres_fv As String
    End Structure

    Private _daneKontrahenta As Kontrahent

    Public Property DaneKontrahenta() As Kontrahent
    Get
        Return _daneKontrahenta
    End Get
    Set(value As Kontrahent)
        _daneKontrahenta = value
    End Set
End Property

    Public Sub PobierzTowaryKontrahenta()
        _daneKontrahenta.adres_fv = ""
        _daneKontrahenda.adres_wys = "a"
    End Sub
End Class
```

And when I try to assign a value from a different class to `daneKlienta.DateKontrahenta.adres_fv` I get following error: Expression Is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment.

So how can I assign a value from that class? It is really important to me to do it this way and please someone explain me why it happens. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is referring to your `Kontrahent` structure.

Because it is a structure and not a class, in the construct

`daneKlienta.DaneKontrahenta.adres_fv =...`

`DaneKontrahenta` is actually a copy of the property held in `daneKlienta`.

That is, the implicit `get` function being invoked at the first dot to get `DaneKontrahenta`from the class returns a copy, not a reference (since `Kontrahent` is not a reference type).

So the assigned value would be immediately thrown away afterwards along with the temporary copy of `DaneKontrahenta`.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh now I understand the difference between class and structure, thanks! So to solve my problem I will change a structure into a class :)